# Why are people using KS statistic to choose cutoff for binary predictions?

Tags: classification, kolmogorov-smirnov-test, empirical-cumulative-distr-fn

I've seen that people are sometimes using Kolmogorov-Smirnov statistic to determine a cutoff in a binary classification models, such as logistic regression. However, i do not fully understand why and what are the implications of such a choice.

So far i've seen two different ways of using KS to choose a cutoff for binary classifier. One is to compare the empirical distribution function of predictions for class 1 and class 0 and place a cutoff where the difference between the EDFs' values is the biggest (as measured by the KS statistic)

This is show in Figure 3 of [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/255560672_An_Analysis_of_the_Applicability_of_Credit_Scoring_for_Micronance) by Van Gool et al., 2012 or it is mentioned in [this paper](https://journal.fsv.cuni.cz/storage/1228_rezac.pdf) on measuring the quality of credit scoring models.

Another approach i've seen is to compare the TPR and FPR using KS statistic as done in [this document](http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/303414_fb0a43efb0d7433983fdc9adcf87317f.html).

I haven't seen a thorough explanation why exactly would one want to choose the cutoff this way? How does this compare to other ways of choosing a cutoff (such as based on the share of class 1 and 0 on all observations? - i.e. if 30% of past observations were class 1, then i would choose to predict class one for the highest 30% of my predictions).

My intuitive understanding is that if i choose a cutoff where the difference between the two EDFs is biggest, then i somehow choose a point such that to the left of it i am adding to group 0 True negatives faster than False negatives (the gap between the two EDFs is opening up),whereas to the right of the chosen point i am adding True positives to group 1 faster than i am adding False positives to it (the gap  between the curves is closing down).

Is my intuition correct? Is there something else i can say about the cutoff? How about a case when the gap between the two curves would first open up, then close, then open up and close again? Would still a cutoff based on KS statistic make sense? (Yes, i know that "whether the choice of cutoff makes sense depends on the costs coming from bad classification").